# Cannot connect to RDS from inside a docker container, I can from the host, and I can from a local docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, metabase

I have an ec2 instance with docker compose installed, running a single container. I have the same setup replicated locally on my machine.

using `nc -v **host** 5432` results in:

- From my machine > success
- From inside a docker container running on my machine > success
- From inside the ec2 instance > success
- From inside a docker container running on the ec2 > Host is unreachable

I'm guessing there's something I'm missing in the ec2's docker config if anyone can point me in the right direction.

This is the docker_boot.service file

```
Description=docker boot
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/metabase
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/docker-compose -f /home/ubuntu/metabase/docker-compose.yml up -d --remove-orphans

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this is your **Docker container** is trying to resolve your RDS DNS using public DNS rather than private one.

1. For a quick workaround, I think you can `nslookup` your **RDS DNS** and take 1 of its IPv4 addresses. Then, use that single IPv4 as your `host`.

```
nslookup <ID>.rds.amazonaws.com
```

2. For a clean workaround, you need to adjust your **Docker container** DNS configuration into your **VPC internal DNS IPv4 address**. Using `--dns`, you can quickly adjust this and you can add more DNS if your application is trying to reach other services as well.

```
docker run --name app --dns=169.254.169.253 -p 80:5000 -d app
```

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html